# SumIf for strings

Tags: excel

Am I able to use the SumIf function for strings? If not, is a UDF the only alternative or is there a way to accomplish this through index somehow potentially?

I am trying to concatenate the values of a table if a cell in the corresponding row is set to "Yes".

### Example:

Chicago  ----------- Yes
New York ---------- (blank)
Los Angeles ------ Yes
Memphis ---------- Yes
San Francisco --- (blank)

Result: Chicago, Los Angeles, Memphis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenating is different than summing when it comes to character encoding (ASCII). SumIf is for summing you can't use it to concatenate. It is important to understand the difference.

I recommend this UDF from a one Mr. Mike Rickson:

```
Function ConcatIf(ByVal compareRange As Range, ByVal xCriteria As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal stringsRange As Range, Optional Delimiter As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, criteriaMet As Boolean

    Set compareRange = Application.Intersect(compareRange, _
    compareRange.Parent.UsedRange)

    If compareRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If stringsRange Is Nothing Then Set stringsRange = compareRange
    Set stringsRange = compareRange.Offset(stringsRange.Row - compareRange.Row, _
    stringsRange.Column - compareRange.Column)

    For i = 1 To compareRange.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To compareRange.Columns.Count
            If (Application.CountIf(compareRange.Cells(i, j), xCriteria) = 1) Then
                ConcatIf = ConcatIf & Delimiter & CStr(stringsRange.Cells(i, j))
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ConcatIf = Mid(ConcatIf, Len(Delimiter) + 1)
End Function
```

Usage:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Thank you for providing that example UDF. How were you able to find it? I had trouble finding anything similar.

Comment: @cardern mrickerson is an OzMVP on OzGrid.

Comment: Could you provide a link if possible? Searching for "OzGrid mrickerson" in google only returns two results, and neither actually link to him... searching for that user on OzGrid does not return anything either.

Comment: Seems like it is mikerickson - not mrickerson.